# Outlet Collection Event

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am creating a settings menu and wanted to implement functionality so that when a user toggles any of the switches, it automatically saves their selection in my sqllite database.

I was thinking about putting each element into an outlet collection, iterating over each element, and adding each event to the same function.

Is there an easier way to do this or is that about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it in a tableview.

Then each cell manages its own UISwitch. The UISwitch also talks back to the cell.

Then in the cell you can call back to the table view controller to update it (with the row index) when the switch is updated.

Comment: ah interesting so any control events that fire within the cell will talk back to the cell, and I can just utilize that to invoke the function. Perfect this is MUCH cleaner! Out of curiosity which function is that?